# Why does my swapCase method returns just one character?

Tags: java, string, swap

I am trying to solve an excercise about a method that returns a new string in which the uppercase letters are changed to lowercase and lowercase letters are changed to uppercase.
It just return the first character of the string, i don't know what keeps causing it.
Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter a string: ");
        String s = input.nextLine();

        System.out.print("The new string is: " + swapCase(s));

    }

    public static String swapCase(String s) {

        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {

            if (Character.isLowerCase(s.charAt(i))) {
                s = String.valueOf(Character.toUpperCase(s.charAt(i)));
            } else if (Character.isUpperCase(s.charAt(i))) {
                s = String.valueOf(Character.toLowerCase(s.charAt(i)));
            }

        }

        return s;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are redefining the String `s` every iteration of your loop. You will want to concatenate your new chararcters to form a final case-swapped string.

```
public static String swapCase(String s) {
    String swapped = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {

        if (Character.isLowerCase(s.charAt(i))) {
            swapped += String.valueOf(Character.toUpperCase(s.charAt(i)));
        } else if (Character.isUpperCase(s.charAt(i))) {
            swapped += String.valueOf(Character.toLowerCase(s.charAt(i)));
        }

    }

    return swapped;
}
```